# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: More than one fragment with the name [spring_web] was found -- How to fix Spring Relative/Absolute Ordering?

Tags: java, spring-mvc, tomcat8

I am trying to run a web app but am having trouble with my pom.xml and Spring dependencies. I cannot tell what it means by absolute ordering.

When I created this app I added the Spring Framework and it imported Spring 4.3.18 but the version I was told to use in the tutorial that I'm following uses 4.1.4. Is that the issue here?

```
26-Mar-2019 20:48:39.597 SEVERE [RMI TCP Connection(9)-127.0.0.1] 
org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal 
ContainerBase.addChild: start: 
org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/eMusicStore]]

Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: More than one 
fragment with the name [spring_web] was found. This is not legal 
with relative ordering. See section 8.2.2 2c of the Servlet 
specification for details. Consider using absolute ordering.



pom.xml 
<groupId>com.mywebsite</groupId>
<artifactId>emusicstore</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <source>7</source>
                <target>7</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>

<dependencies>

    <!-- Spring Framework -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.4.RELEASE</version>
        <!-- should I use 4.1.38 here? -->
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.4.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.4.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Hibernate Framework -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.1.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.0-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.1.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
        <version>4.2.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- jstl and taglibs tags -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>jstl</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>taglibs</groupId>
        <artifactId>standard</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- H2 Database -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
        <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.199</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- FileUpload functionality -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-fileupload</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-fileupload</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
        <version>2.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.5</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Validation Functionality (along with Hibernate Validator) -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
        <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0.GA</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>
```

```
26-Mar-2019 22:16:16.424 SEVERE [RMI TCP Connection(2)-127.0.0.1] 
org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal 
ContainerBase.addChild: start: 
 org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/eMusicStore]]
     at 
org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:167)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:754)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:730)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:734)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.manageApp(HostConfig.java:1736)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:300)
at java.management/com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:809)
at java.management/com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:801)
at org.apache.catalina.mbeans.MBeanFactory.createStandardContext(MBeanFactory.java:483)
at org.apache.catalina.mbeans.MBeanFactory.createStandardContext(MBeanFactory.java:432)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:300)
at java.management/com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:809)
at java.management/com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:801)
at java.management/com.sun.jmx.remote.security.MBeanServerAccessController.invoke(MBeanServerAccessController.java:468)
at java.management.rmi/javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1466)
at java.management.rmi/javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.access$300(RMIConnectionImpl.java:75)
at java.management.rmi/javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl$PrivilegedOperation.run(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1307)
at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.management.rmi/javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doPrivilegedOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1406)
at java.management.rmi/javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.invoke(RMIConnectionImpl.java:827)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
at java.rmi/sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:359)
at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:200)
at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:197)
at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:196)
at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:562)
at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:796)
at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.lambda$run$0(TCPTransport.java:677)
at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:676)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1135)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635)
at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:844)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: More than one fragment with the name [spring_web] was found. This is not legal with relative ordering. See section 8.2.2 2c of the Servlet specification for details. Consider using absolute ordering.
at org.apache.tomcat.util.descriptor.web.WebXml.orderWebFragments(WebXml.java:2200)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.descriptor.web.WebXml.orderWebFragments(WebXml.java:2159)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.webConfig(ContextConfig.java:1124)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.configureStart(ContextConfig.java:769)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.lifecycleEvent(ContextConfig.java:299)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:94)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5181)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
... 44 more

26-Mar-2019 22:16:16.426 SEVERE [RMI TCP Connection(2)-127.0.0.1] org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke Exception invoking method manageApp
 java.lang.IllegalStateException: ContainerBase.addChild: start: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/eMusicStore]]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:758)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:730)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:734)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.manageApp(HostConfig.java:1736)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:300)
at java.management/com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:809)
at java.management/com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:801)
at org.apache.catalina.mbeans.MBeanFactory.createStandardContext(MBeanFactory.java:483)
at org.apache.catalina.mbeans.MBeanFactory.createStandardContext(MBeanFactory.java:432)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:300)
at java.management/com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:809)
at java.management/com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:801)
at java.management/com.sun.jmx.remote.security.MBeanServerAccessController.invoke(MBeanServerAccessController.java:468)
at java.management.rmi/javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1466)
at java.management.rmi/javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.access$300(RMIConnectionImpl.java:75)
at java.management.rmi/javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl$PrivilegedOperation.run(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1307)
at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.management.rmi/javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doPrivilegedOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1406)
at java.management.rmi/javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.invoke(RMIConnectionImpl.java:827)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
at java.rmi/sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:359)
at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:200)
at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:197)
at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:196)
at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:562)
at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:796)
at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.lambda$run$0(TCPTransport.java:677)
at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:676)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1135)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635)
at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:844)

26-Mar-2019 22:16:16.428 SEVERE [RMI TCP Connection(2)-127.0.0.1] org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke Exception invoking method createStandardContext
 javax.management.RuntimeOperationsException: Exception invoking method manageApp
at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:308)
at java.management/com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:809)
at java.management/com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:801)
at org.apache.catalina.mbeans.MBeanFactory.createStandardContext(MBeanFactory.java:483)
at org.apache.catalina.mbeans.MBeanFactory.createStandardContext(MBeanFactory.java:432)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:300)
at java.management/com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:809)
at java.management/com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:801)
at java.management/com.sun.jmx.remote.security.MBeanServerAccessController.invoke(MBeanServerAccessController.java:468)
at java.management.rmi/javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1466)
at java.management.rmi/javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.access$300(RMIConnectionImpl.java:75)
at java.management.rmi/javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl$PrivilegedOperation.run(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1307)
at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.management.rmi/javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doPrivilegedOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1406)
at java.management.rmi/javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.invoke(RMIConnectionImpl.java:827)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
at java.rmi/sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:359)
at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:200)
at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:197)
at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:196)
at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:562)
at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:796)
at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.lambda$run$0(TCPTransport.java:677)
at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:676)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1135)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635)
at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:844)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: ContainerBase.addChild: start: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/eMusicStore]]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:758)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:730)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:734)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.manageApp(HostConfig.java:1736)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:300)
... 35 more
```

Answer (score 0):

you can check the spring dependency in maven repository and see if you are missing. also, it would be helpful if you could post the stacktrace

its looks like you have 2 spring versions in your dependencies.

```
mvn dependency:tree -Dverbose -Dincludes=groupId:artifactId
```

Comment: I added the full stacktrace, thank you for the head's up. I think the dependency is accurate, so I am not sure what is missing.

Comment: @Cospacios looks like you have 2 version of spring  in your config. check your dependency to see if your another spring version.

mvn dependency:tree -Dverbose -Dincludes=groupId:artifactId

Answer (score 0):

I had this error message, when I had not changed Spring versions in 18 months. In my xsi:schemaLocation declaration I was specifying http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd, when I was in fact using Spring version 3.2. Once I changed all of the XML to have http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.xsd, I got an entirely different error message which was in fact my bug. So for the moment, my belief is that having a mismatched schema version can cause this error message in place of a different error.